# Will Thunderbird become the default mail client in the near future?

Tags: thunderbird

I just want to know if there is a plan to replace Evolution with Thunderbird until 12.04

Comment: Any answers to this question would be speculation.

Comment: Aha! We actually have a video of this discussion (see my answer)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thunderbird is now the default email client, starting with 11.10 Oneirc Ocelot.

This was discussed briefly at the Ubuntu Developer Summit. Here's [the blueprint](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/desktop-o-default-email-client) with notes and here is [the summary](http://groups.google.com/group/thunderbird-unity/browse_thread/thread/2124ec3f14c37f99) from the Thunderbird Unity mailing list:

> Currently the etherpad from the
>   session [0] lists these high-level
>   requirements:
>
> - styling improvements
> - CD space
> - e-d-s/calendar integration
> - upgrade reliability (enigmail + binary extensions)

This decision should be made sometime around the Alpha period of 11.10.

Comment: Not to mention Ubuntu-One Support?

Comment: There's support for that somewhere, but according to the notes and memory from the session it wasn't a hard requirement for switching.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no plan for this. If this is something you want to see you should request it on the [Ubuntu Brainstorm](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/). One potential brainstorm idea you might wish to advocate is [Idea #27000](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/27000/)

Comment: Thunderbird has one major problem with its incompatible address book format that has kept it out of opportunities like this for years.

Answer (score 0):

Oneiric (11.10) has been released few days ago.
Now it's a fact: *Thunderbird* is the default email client.

---

Take a look [here](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/desktop-o-default-email-client). Oneiric (11.10) could be first step for *Thunderbird* to become the default client.